# Of two identical VBA functions one suddenly returns a #NAME error

Tags: vba, excel

I've just experienced a sudden failure of one of my macros. It calls upon the following function, which concatenates a series of cells using a selected optional delimiter:

```
Public Function MAKELIST(ByVal cellRange As Range, Optional ByVal delimiter As String)
 'Function to join a range of cells together with an optional
 Dim c As Range
 Dim newText As String
 Dim Count As Integer
 Count = 0
 newText = ""
 For Each c In cellRange
  Count = Count + 1
  newText = newText & c.Value
  If Count < cellRange.Count Then
   newText = newText & delimiter
  End If
 Next
 MAKELIST = newText
End Function
```

It is simply joining together manually-entered cell data--any values at all appear to be breaking it. It appears that the problem lies with how the function is being referred to/called (sorry, not good with the nomenclature) rather than the function itself.

This *was* working perfectly. I moved the file between folders and it suddenly stopped working, returning a `#NAME` error every time. Nothing had changed within the code, so I changed it from `MAKELIST` to `MAKELIST2`, with identical VBA. This works perfectly. However, I obviously don't want to have to change every reference to the function within my workbook, and I want it to be robust and futureproof so this won't happen to other users. Can anyone shed any light on why this might have happened?

Thanks!

Comment: What do the cells in `cellRange` refer to? Formulas? External references?

Comment: Apologies--I've clarified this above. Just text strings.

Comment: Thank you for feeding back. Did you try [brettdj](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11082997/190829)'s answer? Do you have calculation mode set to Automatic?

Comment: Not per se, as the problem wasn't with how the function worked (although I will try to optimise my code further down the line). I do have it set to automatic--as I said in response to @brettdj: is it possible that conflicts can arise due to where a function is stored and how that module is named? I have changed both of those factors and it has come back to life

Comment: Anything is possible, unfortunately none of us know under what conditions you are working. Problems like this are hard to diagnose and what you think is fine might actually be causing the problem.

Comment: I understand--just wanted to check whether this was a symptom of a common mistake. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6):

It would be useful to see the problematic range. Although you could just use this much shorter function

*[Updated to handle multiple column ranges]*

```
Public Function MAKELIST2(ByVal cellRange As Range, Optional delimiter As String)
Dim rng1 As Range
For Each rng1 In cellRange.Columns
    MAKELIST2 = MAKELIST2 & Join(Application.Transpose(rng1), delimiter)
Next
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for this--I haven't tried your answer, as the problem appears to have alleviated itself. Is it possible that conflicts can arise due to where a function is stored and how that module is named? I have changed both of those factors and it has come back to life.